# How to clear a Angularjs child forms model values on hide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to **clear angularjs child forms model values on hide**. I have some kind of condition I use for **ng-if** to hide some part of the form and want that part of the form to be without data if the ng-if condition returns to true again. That's all, that can't be so difficult... ???

```
<form name="parentForm">
<input type="text" name="alwaysRequired" ng-model="model.required" required /> 
<h3>Parent Form</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="showOptionalFormSelected" ng-model="model.showOptional" id="showOptionalForm" /> 
<label for="showOptionalForm">show optional form</label>
<div ng-if="model.showOptional" clear-forms-on-hide>
  <h3>Optional Form</h3>
  <div ng-form="optionalForm">
  <input type="text" name="optionalInputName" ng-model="model.optionalValue" required />
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I would like it to be as easy as possible, without too many directives cluttered around the code.

Everything I tried doesn't work due to the fact that the entire tree of scopes is destroyed while I am trying to get hold of the model bindings and reset those.

- If I would use ng-show it works but all those validators on those inputs freak out and all those forms are marked $invalid.
- If I try to get hold of each ng-model, use it's string-value, get hold of the scope, generate a accessor with $parse I could only use it to work on a destroyed scope.
- I haven't yet tried to use $destroy and hope that the scope is still capable of writing to the model, but I doubt. I am afraid to mess up navigation with that and delete my data while navigating away.
- I tried to collect all those fields in those forms and delete the data in a directive with a higher priority, but those collected ng-models only see destroyed scopes :-/

For that last try I rebuild a small self contained example that reproduces the issue somehow:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('clearForm', [])
  .component('formBox', {
    template: `<div ng-form="{{$ctrl.innerFormName}}"><ng-transclude /></div>`,
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
      innerFormName: '<'
    }
  })
  .component('inputComponent', {
    template: `<input type="text" name="{{$ctrl.inputName}}" ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel" required />`,
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
      inputName: '<',
      ngModel: '='
    }
  })
  .controller('InitModelController', ['$scope', function InitModelController($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
      optionalValue: 'test',
      showOptional: true,
      required: 'important something we need',
      optional2: {
        one: 'one',
        other: 'other',
      },
      componentInput: 'component input'
    };
  }])
  .directive('clearFormsOnHide', function clearFormOnHide() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 700,
      bindings: {
        ngIf: '<',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        if (!attr.ngIf)
          throw new Error('This directive must be used together with ng-if!');

        let formsWatch = null;
        let inputsToClear = [];
        scope.$watch(attr.ngIf, onIfChange);

        function onIfChange(showContent) {
          if (!showContent) {
            if (formsWatch) formsWatch();
            clearKnownInputs();
          } else
            formsWatch = scope.$watch(attr.clearFormsOnHide, collectNgModelElementsFromForms);
        }

        function collectNgModelElementsFromForms(formsToClear) {
          if (!formsToClear)
            throw new Error('No form named ' + attr.clearFormsOnHide + ' found in current scope.', scope);
          if (!window.angular.isArray(formsToClear))
            formsToClear = [formsToClear];
          formsToClear.forEach(collectNgModelsFromForm);
        }

        function collectNgModelsFromForm(form) {
          Object.values(form)
            .filter((ele) => ele && ele.hasOwnProperty('$touched'))
            .forEach(element => inputsToClear.push(element));
        }

        function clearKnownInputs() {
          inputsToClear.forEach(clearNgModel);
          inputsToClear = [];
        }

        function clearNgModel(hiddenNgModel) {
          hiddenNgModel.$rollbackViewValue();
          hiddenNgModel.$setViewValue(null);
          hiddenNgModel.$commitViewValue();

          // eslint-disable-next-line
          hiddenNgModel.$$ngModelSet(hiddenNgModel.$$scope, null);
          hiddenNgModel.$setUntouched();
          hiddenNgModel.$setPristine();
          hiddenNgModel.$render();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div ng-app="clearForm" ng-strict-di ng-controller="InitModelController">
  <form name="parentForm">
    <h3>Parent Form</h3>

    <input type="text" name="alwaysRequired" ng-model="model.required" required />
    <input type="checkbox" name="showOptionalFormSelected" ng-model="model.showOptional" id="showOptionalForm" />
    <label for="showOptionalForm">show optional form</label>
    <div ng-if="model.showOptional" clear-forms-on-hide="[parentForm.optionalForm,parentForm.optionalForm2]">
      <h3>Optional Form</h3>
      <div ng-form="optionalForm2">
        <div ng-repeat="name in ['one','other']">
          <input type="text" name="optionalForm2_{{name}}" ng-model="model.optional2[name]" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ng-form="optionalForm">
        <input type="text" name="optionalInputName" ng-model="model.optionalValue" required />
        <input-component input-name="componentInputName" ng-model="model.componentInput"> </input-component>
        <label for="showOptionalDateCheckbox">show optional date</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionalInputCheckboxName" id="showOptionalDateCheckbox" ng-model="model.optionalCheck" required />
      </div>

    </div>
    <form-box inner-form-name="'boxedOptionalForm'" ng-if="model.optionalCheck" clear-forms-on-hide="[parentForm.boxedOptionalForm]">
      <input type="date" name="optionalDate" ng-model="model.optionalDate" />
    </form-box>
  </form>
  <ul>

    <li>always required value: {{model.required|json}}</li>
    <li>hide optional: {{model.showOptional|json}}</li>
    <li>optional 2 value one: {{model.optional2.one|json}}</li>
    <li>optional 2 value other: {{model.optional2.other|json}}</li>
    <li>optional value: {{model.optionalValue|json}}</li>
    <li>optional checkbox: {{model.optionalCheck|json}}</li>
    <li>optional component input: {{model.componentInput|json}}</li>
    <li>optional date: {{model.optionalDate|json}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We use components for almost anything which doesn't make it easier :-/

- We have a box-component for each visual box that contains the form, which makes it hard to get hold of the form without knowing it's name.
- All input elements are wrapped in components, too. So anything that needs to be next to the input needs to be able to shut off and needs to be configured in all those components and would be discouraged.
- All those child inputs are nested, have different scopes, are inside ng-repeats, depend on each other. That makes it hard to just use their ng-model string in another scope and makes it error-prone to duplicate the logic in the controller to manually delete the model.

Does anybody have a good idea of how you might be able to delete a bunch of model values without specifing them each individually but still using ng-if? It doesn't really matter if it only clears forms or only ng-model values.

Comment: this is a terrible use of `ng-init`;  by using `ng-init`, you lose the ability to do things like creating value defaults.

Comment: But it does have an effect.  Don't add things to your examples that aren't in the actual problem you are trying to solve.  As it stands now, your examples aren't representative of the problem you are facing at all.  You keep talking about nested components and different scopes and not knowing the names of forms and inputs, but your example doesn't show any of that.

Comment: I deleted it from the short code snippet and left it inside the working example as it is used there to show the issue and to help with reproducing it.

Comment: @Claies I extended the example to include most problems and removed the ng-init. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create method `resetModel()` in your directive and change in your code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showOptionalFormSelected" ng-model="model.showOptional" id="showOptionalForm" ng-change="resetModel(model)" />
```

then reset model in resetModel() method.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. I can't reset the whole model, other valid values are contained. I can't restructure the model to change that. I just want to reset a subset which is within those child-forms.

Comment: Yes you can reset single value with in this method. if you don't get it provide me your running pice of code on  some online editor.

Comment: I toggled the code example to be visible by default and enhanced it a little with the component input.